# Whats is the best way to approach - Cont DV and Ordinal IV

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data

I have 15 questions and each question has 4 different statuses like 0 – ‘no action’ 1 – ‘started ‘2- ‘implemented’ and 3 – ‘completed’. I'd like a good way to measure the impact of each question on our in visitors (number of visitors), and if possible apply regression.
1. It is possible to use dummy-encoding to the ordinal variable and use regression ( 3 INV variable – 1,2,3)
2. It is possible to output each dummies Standardized Coefficients  - Beta
3. Also get from R-squared how different independent variables  (dummies) are contributing to a dependent variable ( number visiting)
Please let me know if the above makes sense
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My Apologge - Continuous dependent variable and Ordinal Independent